# Is there any difference between "4.3.5-pnpify" and "4.3.5-sdks"?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

After I run

```
yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode
```

typescript workspace version changed

from

> 4.3.5-pnpify

to

> 4.3.5-sdks

when I ran

```
yarn dlx @yarnpkg/pnpify ....
```

It did not work, because it had deprecated.

My yarn version is 2.4.1

Is there any important difference between that typescript versions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The editor integration has been moved out of `@yarnpkg/pnpify` into `@yarnpkg/sdks` starting from Yarn 3.0 (you can use `@yarnpkg/sdks` with Yarn 2.x too). The TypeScript version ending was changed as well into `-sdks`. If it ends with `-sdks` it means your editor integration script was generated by the newer Yarn code from `@yarnpkg/sdks`, that is all the difference:

https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300